# Splitting instances data returns incorrect output

Tags: java, weka

I'm trying to write a static method that can instantly randomise and split data into training and test set based on the proportion of split that is assigned, and would like some support towards correcting my approach.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Instances[] splitData(Instances all, double proportion) {
    all.randomize(new java.util.Random(0));
    Instances[] split = new Instances[2];

    split[0] = new Instances(all);
    split[1] = new Instances(all, 0);

    double trainsize = proportion * all.numInstances();
    double testsize = all.numInstances() - trainsize;

    split[1] = new Instances(all, (int) trainsize, (int) testsize);

    return split;
}
```

Though when I try to use my method with my data I get:

> [Lweka.core.Instances;@63e2203c

Comment: Show Instances class code.

Comment: Your method returns an array. `System.out.println(...)` does not work with arrays. It will output the class of the object (`[` means this is an array, `L<classname>;` is the name of the class for the array elements; `@...` is the JVM-internal ID of the object).